# iOS: Vector Graphics / Image

Tags: ios, draw, cgcontext, vector-graphics, gpuimage

I have been reading a lot about pixel and vector graphics.

Have also read questions here on SO that discussed about this, most of which have been tagged with `GPUImage`.

Still, I have not been able to find an answer regarding this.

My question is:

How can we be able to produce vector graphics for iOS?

Let's say, for example, we have an `UIImage`, may it be a picture taken from the camera or an image that we created using `CGContext`, is there an algorithm or a way where we could convert this into Vector graphic image?

Or: is there a way to create a vector image within iOS?

I am not here to ask for complete code; I would like to just get some pointer / directions in accomplishing this from those has the know-how. Sample code would be nice, which I doubt I would get, because prior to posting the question here, I have been searching for answers both on Google and here on SO.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, but I'll attempt to answer. If you want to draw vector graphics, you can do that with [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html). (aka Quartz 2D) It creates lines, curves, filled polygons, text, etc. If you have specific questions about how to something with CoreGraphics, please post that as a question with as much detail as you can.

If you want to save drawings that you've made with CoreGraphics in a vector format that other applications or operating systems can recognize, you can [generate a PDF using CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000957-Reference-DontLinkElementID_1).

If you want to convert a photograph into a vector image, that's a very complicated thing to do. It is possible, but the results vary greatly. You will probably need to look up topics like [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection), [image segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation), and other [image analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_analysis) techniques.